# using a Modal to view data in @foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

I would like to show data in a Modal by the ID, but the Modal always shows the same data. It does not matter the row I click, it shows always data from the same row. I don´t know why it is not passing the correct data.

This is the code.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped"id="mitabla" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center" style="width: 40px;">#</th>
      <th><p>Marcar</p><input type="checkbox" id="casilla"></th>
      <th>Host Name </th>
      <th>Nº de Serie </th>
      <th>Modelo</th> 
      <th>Cargador</th>
      <th>Maletín</th>
      <th>Docking</th>
      <th>Ratón / Teclado</th>
      <th>Observaciones</th>
      <th>Usuario</th>
      <th class="text-center" style="width: 100px;">Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <?php foreach($all_informatica as $infor): ?>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo (int)$infor['id'];?></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="casilla" name="casilla[]" value="<?php echo $infor['id'];?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['hostName']))?></td>
        <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['nSerie']))?></td>
        <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['modelo']))?></td>
        <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['cargador']))?></td>
        <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['maletin']))?></td>
        <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['docking']))?></td>
        <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['ratonTeclado']))?></td>
        <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['notas']))?></td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" name="usuario" disabled>
            <option value="">Usuarios</option>
            <?php  foreach ($all_users as $users): ?>
              <option value="<?php echo (int)$users['id']; ?>" <?php if($infor['user_id'] === $users['id']): echo "selected"; endif; ?> >
                <?php echo remove_junk($users['name']); ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-view" id="viewID" name="viewID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-ver" value="<?php echo $infor['id'];?>" title="Ver">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
            </button>
            <a href="edit_informatica.php?id=<?php echo (int)$infor['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" data-href="delete_informatica.php?id=<?php echo (int)$infor['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" title="Eliminar">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </td>
      <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
<div class="pull-left">
  <a href="export_informatica.php" class="btn btn-danger" target="_blank">Exportar PDF</a>
</div>
        
<!-- modal -->
<?php foreach($all_informatica as $infor): ?>       
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-ver" >   
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">  
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Informacion del equipo</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="nombre">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <h2><strong>Host Name portátil : </strong> <?php echo $infor['hostName']; ?> </h2>
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody> 
                  <tr>       
                    <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Host Name</th>
                    <td><?php echo $infor['hostName']; ?></td>
                    <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Nº de Serie</th>
                    <td><?php echo $infor['nSerie']; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Modelo</th>
                    <td><?php echo $infor['modelo']; ?></td>
                    <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Cargador</th>
                    <td><?php echo $infor['cargador']; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Maletín</th>
                    <td><?php echo $infor['maletin']; ?></td>
                    <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Docking</th>
                    <td><?php echo $infor['docking']; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Ratón / Teclado</th>
                    <td><?php echo $infor['ratonTeclado']; ?></td>
                    <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Observaciones</th>
                    <td><?php echo $infor['notas']; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Usuario</th>
                    <td>
                      <select class="form-control" name="usuario">
                        <option value="">Usuarios</option>
                        <?php  foreach ($all_users as $users): ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo (int)$users['id']; ?>" <?php if($infor['user_id'] === $users['id']): echo "selected"; endif; ?> >
                            <?php echo remove_junk($users['name']); ?>
                          </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                      </select>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-print" onclick="javascript:imprSelec('nombre')" ><span class="fa fa-print"> </span>Imprimir</button>
        </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div>
     <!-- /.modal-dialog -->   
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-default -->
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have tried different things, but I always have the same result. Same data every time in the Modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are generating multiple modal dialogs with the same `ID` (`modal-ver`) inside your loop. `ID` must be unique.

So you need to append a new `ID` on each `infor` item every interaction.

```html
<!-- Remove the modal code inside the loop -->
<!-- modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-ver">
  <!-- Modal content here -->
</div>
<!-- End of modal -->

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="mitabla" border="1">
  <!-- Table content here -->
</table>

<!-- Generate a unique modal for each infor item -->
<?php foreach($all_informatica as $infor): ?>
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-ver-<?php echo $infor['id']; ?>">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Informacion del equipo</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="nombre">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <!-- Modal content here -->
              <h2><strong>Host Name portátil : </strong><?php echo $infor['hostName']; ?></h2>
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                  <!-- Table content here -->
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-print" onclick="javascript:imprSelec('nombre')">
            <span class="fa fa-print"></span> Imprimir
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<!-- Update the button to target the specific modal using the unique ID -->
<?php foreach($all_informatica as $infor): ?>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-view" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-ver-<?php echo $infor['id']; ?>" title="Ver">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
  </button>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

With this each modal will have a unique `ID` based of the `infor` item. Every times the loops runs the `ID` will be different form the previous.

Then you need to update the button. So that you are trigger the right item with help of the `ID`.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-view" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-ver-<?php echo $infor['id']; ?>" title="Ver">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
</button>
```

With `-<?php echo $infor['id']; ?>` to the `data-target` attribute the button will associate with that specific modal with that `infor` item.

Comment: If I update the button as you suggest, it does no run. The button does nothing

Comment: I have updated it now

Comment: Perfect, now it is fine. Thank you very much for the help and explanation.